# Connect XLR microphone to amplifier

Tags: amplifier

I am not able to get sound output from my microphone.  How do I Connect my XLR microphone to the amplifier.  The amplifier does not have a mic input. Which slot do I use in that case. Amplifier is Onkyo HT-R340 and microphone is Ahuja AUD 100XLR wired microphone. Have added pics. [image: front side of amplifier][image: back side of the amplifier][image: microphone]

Comment: Please specify the microphone and amplifier you are using, so that we can help you better.

Comment: The fact that there is no mic in should be a hint that you can't do that without a workaround (other gear).

Answer (score 5):

You don't connect a microphone directly to an amplifier, you would normally connect it to a sound board to be able to adjust the eq and volume prior to going to an amp.  The sound board includes a component called a pre-amp which boosts the signal from the level coming off the microphone to the level needed for the amplifier.

A mic signal is at a level called mic level where as an amplifier needs a line level signal.

It is possible to bypass a mixer if you really want to, but you will need a stand alone pre-amp to do this to boost the mic's signal level to line level.

Further, the device you are using here is not an amplifier, it is a receiver.  A receiver is not going to work well for your purposes.  Receivers are designed to decode consumer audio and play it back to consumer speakers at much lower power than a PA.  An amplifier is designed to take professional inputs and output to PA loudspeakers, which take more power to drive.

What you are trying to do, the way you are trying to do it, will simply not work.

Answer (score 0):

The only input on a typical HiFi amplifier that would have a chance at sufficient gain for testing purposes is the phono input.  However, that has a deemphasis filter (RIAA curve) that will be totally unsuitable for microphone input.

You need to get a separate microphone preamp or a mixer with microphone inputs.  For this particular microphone you probably won't need "phantom power" since it is a dynamic one, but having it available is a good idea in case you want to use condenser mics.